# ExtJS: Dynamic Package loading and build profiles

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to use dynamic package loading in my Sencha ExtJS App.

I created the package in my workspace (`sencha generate package SR2000`) and added `SR2000` to the `uses`-Array in app.json:

```
  "requires": [
    "package-loader",
    "font-awesome",
    ...
  ],

  "uses": ["SR2000"],
```

In Application.js i added the loading to `launch`:

```
  launch: function (profile) {

    console.log('Current Config:', Base.config.Config.getConfig());

    Ext.Package.load('SR2000');

    Ext.Viewport.getController().onLaunch();
    Ext.getBody().removeCls('launching');
    this.callParent([profile]);
  },
```

I then watch / build the app with option `-uses`:

```
sencha app watch -uses <build_profile>
```

When loading the app in the Browser i get error 404

The app is trying to load:
`http://localhost:1841/build/development/wolfitsmart/resources/SR2000/SR2000.js`

but the build output for the package is here:
`http://localhost:1841/build/development/wolfitsmart/<build_profile>/resources/SR2000/SR2000.js`

How can i get the package loader to look in the build_profile-Folder, or get the build to put the package in the resources-Folder?

I added the build_profile-Folder to resources in app.json, that did not help:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "path": "resources",
      "output": "shared"
    }
  ],
```

changed to:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "path": "resources",
      "output": "shared"
    },
    {
      "path": "${build.id}/resources"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Some useful instructions for building and using dynamic packages.

```
sencha app build -dev -pac yourpackagename /// build development
sencha app build -pac yourpackagename // build release
sencha app watch -pac yourpackagename 

if (Ext.Package.isLoaded('packagename')) {
        // package is loaded
} else {
  Ext.Package.load('packagename').then(function () {
      // package is loaded
  });
}
```